# cannot list database in postgres

Tags: postgresql, centos

I cannot list/show database in my postgres server (running into centos 7 VM)  using `psql -l` command

i see this error : `psql: FATAL:  database « postgres » is not exist`

Any idea to debug this error ? for information ; this is the pg_hba.conf

```
cat /var/lib/pgsql/11/data/pg_hba.conf
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust

# reject all remote connections
host    all     all     0.0.0.0/0       reject
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somebody dropped the `postgres` database. That is allowed, but not smart, as you see. Use `template1` instead:

```bash
psql -d template1 -l
```

If that doesn't work either, and somebody dropped `template1`, you are in worse trouble. You will have to stop the PostgreSQL server and try `template0` in single-user mode:

```bash
/path/to/software/bin/postgres --single -D /path/to/datadir template0
```

If there is no `template0` either, you have a problem. You'll have to guess the name of an existing database (there must be one). look for strings in the file for `pg_database`:

```bash
strings /path/to/datadir/global/1262
```

And pick something that looks like a database name. Start the server and connect to that database.

---

No matter which of these ways you end up connecting, re-create all the missing databases. Figure out an appropriate template database: best is `template0`, next best is `template1`, last resort is any other database. That template database is called `templ` in the following:

```
CREATE DATABASE postgres TEMPLATE templ;
```

If `template1` or `template0` are missing, re-create them:

```
CREATE DATABASE template1 TEMPLATE templ;
CREATE DATABASE template0 TEMPLATE templ;
```

Connect to the databases you created and drop everything in them except for the empty `public` schema. Then, if you had to create `template0`, secure it:

```
ALTER DATABASE template0 ALLOW_CONNECTIONS FALSE;
```